# Showing that one limit converges faster to $f'(x)$ than another

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

**Background:**

This is from Mark Joshi's book on mathematical finance chapter 7 exercise 9.

**Question:**

> Suppose $f$ is twice-differentiable and $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ is non-zero. Show that 
>   $$ \lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h}$$
>   converges to $f'(x)$ faster than 
>   $$ \lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

The book suggests to take a Taylor expansion and note that in the symmetric case the first term cancels, but it is not clear to me how this would show a faster rate of convergence for one limit as opposed to another. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: you will obtain something like $f(x+h) - f(x-h) = f'(x) (2h) + c_{x,h} h^2$, where $c_{x,h}$ is some value depending on $x$ and $h$ which won't vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor expansion yields
$$
f(x \pm h) = f(x) \pm hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x) + \Theta(h^3)
$$
hence
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(x) + \frac{h}{2}f''(x)  + \Theta(h^2)
$$
and
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} = f'(x)  + \Theta(h^2)
$$
Can you finish the argument?

**UPDATE**

You see that the error in the one-sided expansion is of linear order because of the $f''$ term, but in the two-sided expansion, the approximation error is of order $h^2$, better by an order.

Comment: I believe I can but where does the $O(h^3)$ or $O(h^2)$ come from? Is that from the function $f$ being twice-differentiable?

Comment: Finishing the argument does it suffice to say that since the first limit goes to $f'(x)$ and the other limit still has terms like $\frac{h}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ then it must be slower? In other words what should I say to finish the argument?

Comment: @AndresMejia no since you divided by $h$ on the LHS

Comment: @Wolfy see update; $\Theta$ terms are from the Taylor's Theorem with remainder